# A function is not executed in an unit test

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, kotlin, mocking

I find this hard to explain but will try to keep it as simple as possible
I am writing a unit test in which a function (getQualityControlCheckDataForUplift()) is accessed in another class but it does get into the function and do what it is supposed to, it directly gets to return statement.

This is the function. should I be mocking the `QualityControlCheck` which is a `data class`

I have shortened the code to make it a bit clear and easier to follow

In my test case,

- I load the MAP - qualityControlChecksDataProvider.loadMapWithQCChecksForMilestone()
- Then orderStateMonitor access that map on calling orderStateMonitor.upliftedVolumeUpdated() in test case. which intern accesses `getQualityControlCheckDataForUplift()` via `showQualityControlChecks()`
- cannot get into `getQualityControlCheckDataForUplift()` not sure why

any suggestions will be very helpful
I really apologise if the code is not simple to understand

```
   fun getQualityControlCheckDataForUplift(qualityControlMilestone: QualityControlMilestone, uplift: Float):
        ArrayList<QualityControlCheck>? {
        val qcChecksForUplift: ArrayList<QualityControlCheck>? = ArrayList()
        val qcChecksForMilestone = mapOfQCChecksForMilestone[qualityControlMilestone.milestoneText]
        qcChecksForMilestone?.forEach {
            if (it.uplift == uplift) qcChecksForUplift?.add(it)
        }
        return qcChecksForUplift
    }
```

My test case

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner::class)
class OrderStateMonitorTest : BaseTest() {

 @InjectMocks
    private lateinit var orderStateMonitor: OrderStateMonitor
@Mock
    private lateinit var qualityControlCheckRequiredDuringFuellingBus: QualityControlCheckRequiredDuringFuellingBus
@Mock
    private lateinit var qualityControlChecksDataProvider: QualityControlChecksDataProvider


  @Before
    fun setUp() {
        qualityControlChecksDataProvider = QualityControlChecksDataProvider(offlineDataStorage, app)
    }
  @Test
    fun `upliftedVolumeUpdated abcdefg`() {

        qualityControlChecksDataProvider.loadMapWithQCChecksForMilestone()
        every(fuelOrderValuesProvider.upliftedVolume()).thenReturn(1000.0f)

        orderStateMonitor.upliftedVolumeUpdated()

        verify(qualityControlCheckRequiredDuringFuellingBus, never()).postUnavailable()
        verify(qualityControlCheckRequiredDuringFuellingBus, once()).postAvailable(qualityControlChecks)
    }
}
```

OrderStateMonitor

```
class OrderStateMonitor @Inject constructor(
    private val orderStorage: CurrentOrderStorage,
    private val fuelOrderValuesProvider: FuelOrderValuesProvider,
    private val noServiceRequiredAvailabilityBus: NoServiceRequiredAvailabilityBus,
    private val qualityControlCheckRequiredDuringFuellingBus: QualityControlCheckRequiredDuringFuellingBus,
    private val qualityControlChecksDataProvider: QualityControlChecksDataProvider
) {
     fun upliftedVolumeUpdated() {
        showQualityControlChecks()
    }

       private fun showQualityControlChecks() {
           // WHEN I TRY TO ACCESS ` //qualityControlChecksDataProvider.getQualityControlCheckDataForUplift` IT DOES NOT GET INTO THAT FUNCTION
              val qualityControlChecks =
                qualityControlChecksDataProvider.getQualityControlCheckDataForUplift(
                    QualityControlMilestone.FUELLING, 1000.0f)
    }
}
```

QualityControlChecksDataProvider

```
class QualityControlChecksDataProvider @Inject constructor(
    private val offlineDataStorage: OfflineDataStorage,
    private val app: App
) {
    private val mapOfQCChecksForMilestone = LinkedHashMap<String, ArrayList<QualityControlCheck>?>()

    fun loadMapWithQCChecksForMilestone() {
        QualityControlMilestone.values().forEach {
            mapOfQCChecksForMilestone.put(it.milestoneText, getQualityControlCheckDataForMilestone(it))
        }
    }

    fun getQualityControlCheckData(qualityControlMilestone: QualityControlMilestone):
        ArrayList<QualityControlCheck>? =
        mapOfQCChecksForMilestone[qualityControlMilestone.milestoneText]

    fun getQualityControlCheckDataForUplift(qualityControlMilestone: QualityControlMilestone, uplift: Float):
        ArrayList<QualityControlCheck>? {
       //DOES NOT GET INTO THIS FUNCTION  I RUN THE TEST CASE
        val qcChecksForUplift: ArrayList<QualityControlCheck>? = ArrayList()
        val qcChecksForMilestone = mapOfQCChecksForMilestone[qualityControlMilestone.milestoneText]
        qcChecksForMilestone?.forEach {
            if (it.uplift == uplift) qcChecksForUplift?.add(it)
        }
        return qcChecksForUplift
    }
  //THERE ARE OTHER PRIVATE FUNCTION WHICH THE ABOVE CODE WILL ACCESS WHICH WORK FINE
}
```

Comment: when loading the map, Does it declared as static?

Comment: Hi thank you for replying, `QualityControlChecksDataProvider` is mocked in the test case, sorry i missed to copy that here initially, I updated my question now which has the mock of `QualityControlChecksDataProvider `
is this what you mean? or am I missing anything

Comment: Let me recap, you ant to test this method `getQualityControlCheckDataForUplift` which no access to it directly, right?

Comment: I am not testing that method exactly, but I am accessing that method which should return QCChecks from the MAP, but issue is the code does not enter that function at all.

Comment: Yes because you mocked `QualityControlChecksDataProvider`, you can use `SPY` or mock with `CALL_REAL_METHOD`

Comment: can you give an example please. I do not quite catch that

Comment: I wrote an answer, hope this help

Comment: any luck for solving the problem!

Comment: trying it, will update you shortly but the spy did not work though

Answer (score 0):

The method not executed because you mocked the class

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner::class)
class OrderStateMonitorTest : BaseTest() {

 @InjectMocks
    private lateinit var orderStateMonitor: OrderStateMonitor
@Mock
    private lateinit var qualityControlCheckRequiredDuringFuellingBus: QualityControlCheckRequiredDuringFuellingBus

    private lateinit var qualityControlChecksDataProvider: QualityControlChecksDataProvider


  @Before
    fun setUp() {
        qualityControlChecksDataProvider = spy(QualityControlChecksDataProvider(offlineDataStorage, app))
    }
  @Test
    fun `upliftedVolumeUpdated abcdefg`() {

        qualityControlChecksDataProvider.loadMapWithQCChecksForMilestone()
        every(fuelOrderValuesProvider.upliftedVolume()).thenReturn(1000.0f)

        orderStateMonitor.upliftedVolumeUpdated()

        verify(qualityControlCheckRequiredDuringFuellingBus, never()).postUnavailable()
        verify(qualityControlCheckRequiredDuringFuellingBus, once()).postAvailable(qualityControlChecks)
    }
}
```

or use `CALL_REAL_METHOD`

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner::class)
class OrderStateMonitorTest : BaseTest() {

 @InjectMocks
    private lateinit var orderStateMonitor: OrderStateMonitor
@Mock
    private lateinit var qualityControlCheckRequiredDuringFuellingBus: QualityControlCheckRequiredDuringFuellingBus

    private lateinit var qualityControlChecksDataProvider: QualityControlChecksDataProvider

// java syntax
@before
public void setUp(){
  qualityControlChecksDataProvider = mock(QualityControlChecksDataProvider, Mocktio.CALL_REAL_METHOD);
}

  @Test
    fun `upliftedVolumeUpdated abcdefg`() {
        qualityControlChecksDataProvider.loadMapWithQCChecksForMilestone()
        every(fuelOrderValuesProvider.upliftedVolume()).thenReturn(1000.0f)

        orderStateMonitor.upliftedVolumeUpdated()

        verify(qualityControlCheckRequiredDuringFuellingBus, never()).postUnavailable()
        verify(qualityControlCheckRequiredDuringFuellingBus, once()).postAvailable(qualityControlChecks)
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried 
val qualityControlCheckDataProviderx = spy(QualityControlChecksDataProvider::class.java)
        every(qualityControlCheckDataProviderx.getQualityControlCheckDataForUplift(ArgumentMatchers.any(), ArgumentMatchers.anyFloat())).thenReturn(qualityControlChecks)

Comment: org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: Unable to create mock instance of type 'QualityControlChecksDataProvider'